# cell.imageView returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am using Pars in this project and specially PFQueryTableViewController which subclasses PFTableViewCell instead of UITableViewCell.

`cell.textLabel`and `cell.detailTextLabel`are set no problem but `cell.imageView` returns nil. Why?

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {
    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PFTableViewCell
    if let podcast = object {
        if let name = podcast["name"] as? String {
            cell.textLabel!.text = name
      }

        if let artist = podcast["artist"] as? String{
            cell.detailTextLabel!.text = artist
        }

        if let artwork = podcast["artwork"] as? PFFile {
            print(cell.imageView)
//                cell.imageView!.file = artwork
//                cell.imageView?.loadInBackground()
             print("we have the artwork \(artwork)")
        } else {
            cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "place")
            print("using placeholder image")
        }

    }

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So first, do you mean imageView is nil or do you mean imageView.image is nil? If your imageView is nil, that means the whole imageView is not being instantiated. How are you creating this imageView? Are you using a storyboard or a nib or are you creating the imageView programmatically? If you are doing it programmatically, make sure you are calling the init method on UIImageView before you try setting its .image property.

If the problem is that the .image property on your UIImageView is nil, then perhaps you have added your image incorrectly to your Images.xcassets folder or you have slightly misspelled the name of the image.

If the problem is you can't see the image, the perhaps if you have created the UIImageView programmatically, you haven't added it to your viewController's view heirarchy. This can be done with

```
 self.view.addSubview(imageView)
```

So first narrow these things down, and if you come back with more information, then it will give me a better idea of the issue.

Comment: Thank you Colin.  I Use PFQueryTableViewController to populate my tableView data. My cell is of type PFTableViewCell. The imageView is not instantiated at all. Also see: https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#user-interface-pfimageview I should just need to call it as I have done.